# Remove vertical space around align equations

Tags: spacing, align

Formed with the alignment occurs in the equation some gaps.

I tried to indicate with red arrows.

[image]

This is without gaps like I mentioned with the ellipse how can i do?

Sorry for my English.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent \lipsum[2] 
\begin{align*}
       & x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \leq 10 \\
       & x_5+x_5 \leq 8 \\
       & x_7+x_8 \leq 5 
     \end{align*}

\noindent \lipsum[4]

{\centering $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \leq 10$

$x_2+x_3 \leq 8$

$x_1+x_3 \leq 5$ \\}

\noindent \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `lipsum` is causing some extra space. Use `\lipsum*[2]` and don't leave blank line between it and `align`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example is somewhat flawed, as [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) inserts a `\par` at the end of every paragraph. As such, you're actually left with an empty line before the `align` (a display math equation) - something you should avoid. One way to avoid this is to load `lipsum` with the `nopar` option:

```
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
```

Alternatively, use `\lipsum*[<nums>]`.

Now for the real changes:

Space above/below a display math equation is regulated by 4 different lengths: Two for the space *above* and two *below*. For each of these locations, the two lengths are dependent on whether the preceding/following line is short or not.

```
\abovedisplayskip% Default: 12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt
\abovedisplayshortskip% Default: 0pt plus 3pt
\belowdisplayskip% Default: 12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt
\belowdisplayshortskip% Default: 7pt plus 3pt minus 4pt
```

You can adjust these to suit your needs, of course. Finally, `align` uses a length `\jot` that influences the space between the multi-line equation. Adjust `\jot` to suit your needs as well.

Here's a minimal example that completely removes any spaces around the `align` as well as the inter-equation spacing (effectively setting all of the above-mentioned lengths to `0pt`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] 
\begin{align*}
  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 &\leq 10 \\
  x_5+x_5         &\leq 8 \\
  x_7+x_8         &\leq 5 
\end{align*}
\lipsum[4]

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}% Inter-equation spacing
\lipsum[2] 
\begin{align*}
  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 &\leq 10 \\
  x_5+x_5         &\leq 8 \\
  x_7+x_8         &\leq 5 
\end{align*}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is really new for me (\par befor align) is it a bug or features?

Comment: @touhami: The idea is to avoid it. Or what do you mean?

Comment: As you said. I should not leave a blank line before align?

Comment: @touhami: Correct. The same goes before _any_ display math equation (`equation`, `equation*`, ``\[..\]``).