# Space between text and begin{align}

Tags: spacing

As you can see below, when I use \begin{align} \end{align}, the space before the equation is bigger than the space after the equation.

I want both spaces to be like the second space after the equation. The first one is too big.

[image]

All I do is write

```
text

\begin{align} stuff \end{align}

text
```

... I tried writing

```
text
\begin{align} stuff \end{align}
text
```

but then the space is too small (even smaller than the second red line above).

I just want both spaces to be like the second red line.

Comment: please do not deface questions in this way.

Comment: From the [editing history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/535711/revisions), it seems OP has solved by himself. You can add "solved" to your problem description or answer by yourself. There is no need to edit and delete the original informative question description, let alone replace with dump text.

Comment: Duplicate (don't separate text and display by a blank line): [Remove vertical space around align equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237762)